# How to make a prolog program return the value it computed

Tags: prolog

(I'm not sur if return is the right word to describe it, but that's the best one I could find.)

I am trying to write a small program in prolog that uses the function add to do multiplications. When I run add by itself or even when it is called by the function test the result is "Z = the sum" ex: if I run  add(2,3,Z) it will display Z=5.
My problem is that I can't get it to do the same thing when I call mult. The only solution that I found is to use write, but that's not the same thing. I tried a lot of stuff but most of it wasn't even compiling and the rest didn't change anything. Does anybody know how I could make it do that ("Z = the product")? What would be the way to make it do that (return) for a program in general?

Thank You

```
add(X,Y,Z) :- 
     Z is X + Y.

mult(X,Y,Z1):-
     multiply(X,Y,0).

multiply(_,0,_):-
     write(0).
multiply(0,_,Z):-
     write(Z).
multiply(X,Y,Z):-
     X > 0,
     add(Y,Z,Z1),
     X1 is X - 1,
     multiply(X1,Y,Z1).
multiply(X,Y,Z):-
     Y < 0,
     X1 is abs(X),
     Y1 is abs(Y),
     multiply(X1,Y1,Z).
multiply(X,Y,Z):-
     Y1 is Y * -1,
     add(Y1,Z,Z1),
     X1 is X + 1,
     multiply(X1,Y,Z1).


test(X,Y,Z1):-
     add(X,Y,Z1).
```

Comment: `multiply(X,Y,Z1):- Z1 is X*Y`

Comment: `mult(X,Y,Z1):-
     multiply(X,Y,0).` what does this rule mean? It doesn't seem logical.

Comment: Well the user calls it like mult(2,3,Z) where Z should be the variable where the product is stored. So I'm initializing Z to zero in order to add Y X times to it and get the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by adding a 4th parameter. I don't know if it is the right way to do it but it works.

```
mult(X,Y,Z):-
    multiply(X,Y,0,Z).

multiply(_,0,_,Z):-
    Z is 0.
multiply(0,_,Z1,Z):-
    Z is Z1.
multiply(X,Y,Z1,Z):-
    X > 0,
    add(Y,Z1,Z2),
    X1 is X - 1,
    multiply(X1,Y,Z2,Z).
multiply(X,Y,Z1,Z):-
    Y < 0,
    X1 is abs(X),
    Y1 is abs(Y),
    multiply(X1,Y1,Z1,Z).
multiply(X,Y,Z1,Z):-
    Y1 is Y * -1,
    add(Y1,Z1,Z2),
    X1 is X + 1,
    multiply(X1,Y,Z2,Z).
```